# How do I add colour to this and make it look better for the user?

Tags: python, gtk, edit, pretty-print

I can Add boxs and Tables

Also the Quit button does not work can someone edit that part of the code please

```
import gtk

class helloworld:

        def close(self,widget): 
                print "I'm outta here" 
                gtk.main_quit()

        def printit(self,widget,lab1): 
                print lab1.get_text() 

        def filllab(self,widget,lab1): 
                lab1.set_text(widget.get_text()) 

        def __init__(self): 
                window = gtk.Window() 
                window.set_size_request(300,400) 
                vbox = gtk.VBox() 
                window.add(vbox)

                lab1 = gtk.Label("shazbut")

                # entry widget 
                ent1 = gtk.Entry() 
                ent1.connect("activate",self.filllab,lab1)

                # quit 
                quitb = gtk.Button("quit",gtk.STOCK_QUIT) 
                quitb.set_size_request(50,100) 
                quitb.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

                printb = gtk.Button("print") 
                printb.connect("clicked",self.printit,lab1) 

                # Pack widgets in the vbox 
                vbox.add(ent1) 
                vbox.add(lab1) 
                vbox.add(quitb) 
                vbox.add(printb)

                window.show_all()

helloworld() 
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The "quit" button doesn't work because you connected the "destroy" signal to the button instead of the clicked signal

```
quitb.connect("clicked", gtk.main_quit)
```

Also, you forgot to connect the window destroy event (so the program will never exit when you click the window close button). Add

```
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
```

To change the label properties use the pango attributes

```
def _add_attributes_to_label(self,label):
        attr = pango.AttrList()

        fg_color = pango.AttrForeground(65535, 0, 0,0,-1)
        strike = pango.AttrStrikethrough(True,0,-1)
        size = pango.AttrSize(30000, 0, -1)

        attr.insert(fg_color)
        attr.insert(size)
        attr.insert(strike)

        label.set_attributes(attr)
```

In your **init** function call the previous function like this:

```
self._add_attributes_to_label(lab1)
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/pango/) to know more about pango attributes.